# Flutter Web - Unable to compile, dual import issues in package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/whiteboardkit#-installing-tab-) in a browser-based app. When trying to compile to Chrome, I get this:

> Compiler message:
>   /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/whiteboardkit-0.1.8/lib/gesture_whiteboard_controller.dart:63:15:
>   Error: 'Point' is imported from both 'dart:math' and 'dart:ui'.
>           ..add(Point.fromOffset(position));
>                 ^^^^^ /C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/whiteboardkit-0.1.8/lib/gesture_whiteboard_controller.dart:77:39:
>   Error: 'Point' is imported from both 'dart:math' and 'dart:ui'.
>         this.draw.lines.last.points.add(Point.fromOffset(secondPoint));

This appears package specific, so I guess my question is why would there be a conflict between 'dart:math' and 'dart:ui'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question why would there be a conflict between `ui` and `math` cannot be answered but only given a reason. In math definitely there is a concept call `Point` and hence there is class defining this. In `dart:ui` you are dealing with a 2D coordinate system based screen or canvas to draw and hence a `Point` refers to one of this points in the screen.

You can simply hide one of this `Point` from one of the imports like this.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' hide Point;
import 'dart:math';
```

or the other way around.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' ;
import 'dart:math' hide Point;
```

Alternative use an alias for the import and use it with the alias as a prefix.

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:math';

// and somewhere in the code use it like 

add(ui.Point.fromOffset(position));
```

Comment: Thanks Abhilash, that helps. As this is a whiteboard package, I guess it'd be better to hide the math Point?
Nevertheless, I'll play around with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped you.. Could you accept the answer as well.  So that people know its answered. :)

Comment: Sorry, seems I clicked in the wrong place. Explains a lot, I guess...